# SQL Returning Months Between a Min and Max Date

Tags: sql, oracle, max, min

I have a table of employee information, with one of the fields being hiredate.

How do I first, retrieve the months between the youngest and most senior employee,

then take this number and round it to the nearest whole number (and name this field "Old Vs. Young"?

Thanks

Comment: please read [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Learn to say "column" rather than "field" if you are going to work with relational databases like Oracle; and do NOT form a habit to give names with spaces and dots to your columns. `old_vs_new` is a much better column name than the one you chose.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has the function `months_between()` to compute the difference in months, and `round()` to - well, you guessed it, round. The solution below shows you also how to "name" a column (how to give it an "alias" - the technical term for this operation).

Using the EMP table in the standard SCOTT schema as an example:

```
select min(hiredate) as min_date, max(hiredate) as max_hiredate,
       round( months_between( max(hiredate), min(hiredate) ) ) as diff_months
from   emp
;


MIN_HIREDATE  MAX_HIREDATE     DIFF_MONTHS
------------  ------------ ---------------
1980-12-17    1987-05-23                77
```